# copy function to local variable and keep this-pointer

Tags: javascript

I have a function on a prototype like this:

```
Car.prototype.drive = function() {
   this.currentSpeed = this.speed;
}
```

I want to call this function very often in another function which is also part of the prototype Car. And because I'm lazy I don't want to rewrite the `this` all the time. So I would like to copy a reference to the function to a local variable:

```
Car.prototype.doSomeThing = function() {
    var driveReference = this.drive;
    driveReference();
}
```

*But* when I call `driveReference()`, the `this`-pointer of `driveReference()` points to `Window` instead to my instance of `Car`.

Is there any possibility to prevent that? 
(`apply()` would work, but that is even more verbose then using `this`)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to bind the context of a function to whatever you like:

```
Car.prototype.doSomeThing = function() {
    var driveReference = this.drive.bind(this);
    driveReference();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write

```
var driveRef = this.drive.bind(this);
```

but [that can have some possibly unwanted performance impact](http://benediktmeurer.de/2015/12/25/a-new-approach-to-function-prototype-bind/).  Or you could just copy `this` to a shorter variable name:

```
var me = this;
me.drive();
```

Explicitly using a reference to the context object is a pretty basic design feature of JavaScript, so it's hard to get around it.

Comment: Looks very nice, but unfortunately performance is crucial for me... maybe I just have to accept `this`

Comment: @treeno using a separate variable (like `me` in my example) won't have a performance impact, but it's not much of an improvement.

Comment: I meant the bind()-thing. The shortcut `me` would't be a big improvement - as you already said